# Should I use auto_open/close or workbook_open/beforeclose to run VBA on open?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel 2003/2007, in which cases should I use auto_open/auto_close routines, and in which cases should I use the workbook_open/workbook_beforeclose events instead?

Apart from backward compatibility to prehistoric versions of Excel, the difference I'm aware of is that one is public and one is private. What (if any) are the other differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a long time once choosing between the opening variants of these, and we used Auto_Open. The main rationale was because if anyone runs the following code:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

... then the Workbook_Open event will not fire. I had a feeling there was another situation where Workbook_Open didn't work either, but I can't remember it now.

I don't have a strong opinion about the close events, but to be honest I'd use the Auto_Close there too. At the end of the day, it's had more testing.

Comment: While `Workbook.Open` is an event, it's also a reserved subroutine as `Workbook_Open`. If you have a `Sub Workbook_Open` subroutine in your ThisWorkbook object, then, on opening of that workbook, the subroutine *will* run, even if the first thing that subroutine does is `Application.EnableEvents = False`.... just for clarification. That EnableEvents line will only prevent `Workbook.Open` from working *later on in the same VBAProject object*.

Comment: That's true - the situation I'm talking about is when another workbook you opened in the same Excel session has disabled events. In which case your workbook won't run the open event when you open it. I know it sounds weird and unlikely but I was working on investment banking and it's actually surprisingly common when you're messing with lots of sheets with large amounts of VBA in them.